# What is the correct way of communicating with the Family Court in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, civil-procedure, family-law, court

I have ongoing proceedings at https://courttribunalfinder.service.gov.uk/courts/croydon-magistrates-court-and-family-court

I had a hearing on 20th Nov 2017.
Next hearing is scheduled for February.
I'd like to include additional information.

> Mr Stefanow understands there will be a chance to speak to the Cafcass and the Court in January and February 2018.
>
> Before these dates there is an opportunity for a few “back and forth” iterations, so that by the time we see each other in person, we will obtain more information - therefore have more productive hearing.

Back in a day (form C100) I had to send 4 copies to the court.

#### Option A:

Send 4 copies to the Court, suggest they should pass the copies to other parties.

#### Option B:

Send a copy to each party involved. *(not sure if I have the latest postal address)*

Tell the Court copies have been sent.

*(I don't think that is allowed, I believe all communication should be routed via the Court)*

#### Option C:

Do something else.

#### Option D:

Do nothing.
Communication with Court, despite best intentions, is not recommended, not advisable.

---

Surely there is an established standard.

Just don’t tell me me “consult your lawyer”, the situation is pretty simple here.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/email-guidance